# PHP - Check if file exists on FTP server with no SIZE support

Tags: php, ftp

Yes, I know, it's hard to believe those FTP servers still exist, but they actually do. IBM iSeries machines run such servers.

I've already got an answer which involves `ftp_nlist` and `in_array` but, as some of you may have guessed, this is *slow* when a directory contains a large number of items.

Due to the lack of support of SIZE, `fopen` always fails when used in read mode (remember that `x` isn't supported by the FTP wrapper), while `ftp_size` always returns `-1` (that was expected) and `file_exists` always returns `false` (maybe because it uses SIZE internally?).

- `ftp_get` and `ftp_fget` do the trick, but they download the whole file if it exists. Not very good. One possible solution involves the use of `ftp_fget` passing an handler of a file opened in read mode only, and catching the raised warning. It's different when the file doesn't exist, but this solution feels uncouth, and I don't really know if it's feasible (maybe someone can give an example).
- Another solution uses `ftp_nb_get`/`ftp_nb_fget` to try to retrieve the file. If the function returns `0` (`FTP_FAILED`) then the file presumably doesn't exist. I'd still have to deal with a temporary local file, and it sucks to close and reopen the connection if  `FTP_MOREDATA` is returned (or else other FTP commands couldn't be issued).

Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: When using `ftp_nlist`, how slow is it actually?

Comment: I'd try to do the trick: use `ftp_rename($connection, $testedFile, 'someThingThatDoesntExists');` if it fails, then we have our answer (_'NO'_. But that relies on fact, that destination is writeable and we have permission to do renaming). If it succeeded, then rename it back and we also have our answer (_'YES'_). I didn't test that, but you may try and say what will happen.

Comment: @silkfire It may take up to a minute for 5000+ files, but even a couple of seconds would be too much for a task like that.

Comment: @MaxArt Well okay, could you benchmark it? How long does the retrieval of a file list take? And searching with `in_array`?

Comment: @AlmaDo That a dirty little trick and it seems it actually does the work but, granted that I want primarily to know if a file exists to avoid to overwrite it, this make the file sort of disappear for a short time. Nice effort anyway.

Comment: Well - with your server you'll be able to resolve via some "dirty trick", I afraid. And that allows you to avoid file transfers. But it will cause sort break, yes

Comment: @silkfire It took 43.76 seconds for 5407 files. The following benchmarks took something like 0.4 seconds only, due to some sort of server-side cache I guess? But I can't rely on that.

Comment: @AlmaDo It seems there's a simpler way: I can use `ftp_rename` to rename the file to itself. Since using `ftp_rename` is basically your idea, if you put everything in an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Hm. yes it will. Ok. _coming soon_

Comment: @MaxArt May I ask why you need to know if the file is stored on server? I'm asking because the answer is nothing worth, if you try to access the file later, because it may have been deleted meanwhile. If you just need a directory listing use `ftp_nlist` otherwise **just do** the file operation and check for errors

Comment: @hek2mgl I've already stated (read above) that the main task is to avoid to overwrite a file with a STOR command. The FTP server of the iSeries does have a command that prevents this to happen, but it's a custom command and I want to keep my script as generic as possible. The accepted answer is good enough, although it leaves a brief open window between the renaming and the storing commands.

Comment: @hek2mgl By the way, I hope you're not the one who downvoted *the question*. That seriously puzzles me.

Comment: I did. Because this post is definitely not a +4. Have you read FTP specs? why should you need the `SIZE` command for that? (XY problem) Maybe I wasn't clear enough, you can use `LIST` for file names as well as directories

Comment: @hek2mgl What part you don't understand about the fact that's a lengthy operation? And what does that have to do with *the question*? Are you trolling or what?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `LIST /path/to/file` ? Do you understand now? Why do you missing the `SIZE` command?

Comment: @hek2mgl If you do have an answer, why don't you put everything in an answer?! I was asking for help here, not pointless debate! And it *still* doesn't explain why you downvoted *the question*.

Comment: @MaxArt I don't like the word "pointless" said by guys you are obviously not able to tell what it "pointless" and what not. I spent the last 3 hours to find a solution for you. Sorry that my solution is not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: @hek2mgl If it's an alternative, **write down the answer!** I might even accept it. That's what StackOverflow is for: people read the answers first, if you want to help them then do it!

Comment: I'll do. (but later, need to leave office soon) I had already an answer,but then not posted it because I wanted be 100% sure before.. That's why stzarted the discussion. not to harm anybody..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SIZE` command is not required. You can simply use the function `ftp_nlist()` for that because the FTP `LIST` command allows to pass a directory as well as file as it's argument.

Although the PHP documentation is missing to mention that it is specified in [RFC 959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) (page 32) and is working. Here comes an example. (Thanks `Debian!`)

```
$server = 'ftp.us.debian.org';
$port   =  21; 
$user   = 'anonymous';
$pwd    = 'foo@bar.xxx';

$conn = ftp_connect($server);
$ret = ftp_login($conn, $user, $pwd);

foreach(array(
    'debian/README.html',
    'NOT_FOUND.html'
) as $file) {
    $listing = ftp_nlist($conn, $file);
    if(empty($listing)) {
        echo "$file was not found on $server\n";
    } else {
        echo "$file was found on $server\n";
    }
}
```

Or, expressed as a function:

```
function ftp_file_exists(
    $server,
    $filename,
    $user = 'anonymous' ,
    $pwd = '',
    $port = 21
) {
    $conn = @ftp_connect($server);
    if($conn === FALSE) {
        die("Failed to connect to $server");
    }

    $ret = @ftp_login($conn, $user, $pwd);
    if($ret === FALSE) {
        die("Failed to login at $server");
    }

    $listing = @ftp_nlist($conn, $file);
    if($listing === FALSE) {
        die("Failed to obtain LIST response from $server");
    }

    return !empty($listing);
}
```

---

In comments there came up a discussion how useful and reliable the results of `LIST` can be. Let me say some additional sentences to that...

**Creating files on server**

Please be aware of the fact that you should avoid to rely on something like:

```
if(file_not_exists_on_server($filename)) {
    create_file_on_server($filename);
}
```

because it is possible that the file will be created by another client between the first and second function. While this is true on local file systems as well, it can happen in distributed client server applications more easily, because of longer response times compared to a local filesystem and because of possibly many, even anonymous clients (like in the example above)

When creating files remotely I would suggest to follow a strong naming scheme in public writable folders in order to avoid collisions. When following this scheme, then just write and don't care. The worst thing which can happen is that you overwrite something which somebody other has created by accident. But who creates something like `/client/id/file_name.txt` by accident?

---

**Downloading files from server or moving, deleting files on server**

When attempting one of those operations, *don't care* about if the files exists or not before the operation. Just do it. But if it fails, you need to handle the errors properly.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, as this one involves no operations on files. I've already tested it in my case and it works.

Comment: @MaxArt Thx :) After all I have to admit that your question is a good question and it was fun to solve. At the end, it was basically  a lack of documentation in the php manual. Also I have to say that over a long time I understood your question like "how to *ensure* that the file is present", but you didn't said that. However I've added some sentences regarding that. (Maybe I was so focused on that detail because this pointed out as a problem in a former project of mine).. If you could edit your question (just add a space or whatever, but it is required by SO) , then I'll upvote it..

Answer (score 2):

You can use some kind of *"dirty trick"*: try to do [`ftp_rename()`](http://php.net/ftp_rename) on tested file. Sample would be:

```
$result = ftp_rename($connection, $testedFile, $testedFile);
```

if it will fail, then we have most probably non-existent file. It's not 100% unless you're sure about permissions issues. But if it will succeed - then file definitely exists. I doubt that there's another way which can be used and allow you to avoid file transferring to local FS or dealing with full directory listing.

Comment: Thanks man, I hope this helps other developers in the same situation.

Comment: I've upvoted this, but now realizing I shouldn't. The result of the suggested solution is nothing worth if it should be used in a later command, because the file may have been deleted or created in the meantime between the command and the above operation. There are just two ways how to do it: You want a dir listing? Use `ftp_nlist()`. You want to perform a file operation? Perform it and check for errors. That's it since the very beginning of multitasking OS. However, on FTP the option "Create file if not exists" still isn't present. With or without the SIZE command. ...

Comment: Clearly spoken using the SIZE command here would be wrong and vulnerable against race conditions. Also your solution just says that the file did exists (or not) **during the check**. It does not tell that the file does exists (not exists) **in the moment** when trying to create it. This is what the OP don't get. The answer is misleading and may harm other developers, it will not help them. So we'll hope that no none copies this.

Comment: It isn't accurate. But it _will_ answer properly for _the moment of check_. It has nothing to do neither with concurring connections nor with some code that will probably be after that

Comment: @AlmaDo Man!! Don't you get it? The question is **Why** do you perform this check? If you just want to have a snapshot of the current situation on server (during check) then use a dir listing ( ftp_nlist)

Comment: `ftp_nlist($conn_id, $filename)` has the **same** worth as this

Comment: No. it seems, it's you who have missed some point. Re-read OP's question then. I don't know how to explain better

Comment: You need to read it again and tell me why `ftp_nlist($conn_id, $filename)` shouldn't fit here. Can you tell a reason?

Comment: If this is really to slow, the pure `LIST` can be used .. It supports file names as well as directories

Comment: According to your own doubts about "during the check only" existense. How will `ftp_nlist` help? It will also show situation _on the moment when call was done_. So - yes, file can be later deleted/moved/or/whatever. So what's the difference?

Comment: I don't told that it will "help". I told (multiple times) "You want a dir listing? Use ftp_nlist(). You want to perform a file operation? Perform it and check for errors."

Comment: @hek2mgl Good Lord... What if I just want to know if a file is there or not? Don't you really get it?

Comment: @MaxArt I told that 1000 times: If you want that use `LIST filename`

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, it is and I've accepted it. (Sorry Alma Do, but that one *is* better, although your one still works.) What's still not clear to me is that why you downvoted the question ("this post is definitely not a +4" is not a reason)...

Comment: @MaxArt well. lol. What can I say. dv and then _"After all I have to admit that your question is a good question and it was fun to solve"_ when you've accepted the answer (while it _may_ be good, I still can't understand what's the reason of such rage against one simple operation). Huh `//no comments (as for "function" which doing die() on each fail)`

Answer (score 0):

What about file_exists(), or other stat() family functions?  FTP wrapper supports it.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php

Comment: As I clearly stated in the question, `file_exists` doesn't work. Stat functions don't work either ("stat failed" error) and `is_file` always returns `false`.